# How to run forever tool for node in vagrant provision shell

Tags: node.js, shell, vagrant, forever

I'm new to vagrant and I am setting up a Node.js CentOs 6.5 x86_64 development machine in VirtualBox 4.3.6 and package it to a vagrant box. My host OS is windows 8.1 Pro.

What I am trying to do is to create a provision in shell that when running `vagrant up` the `bootstrap.sh` will check if `app.js` exist in the project directory if it doesn't exist it will create a temporary app.js and run `forever start -w app.js`.

Everything is working in the bash script but when it reaches the line `forever start -w app.js` I get this error.

```
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 14: forever: command not found
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 14: forever: command not found
```

Running `forever start -w app.js` in vagrant ssh works fine with no problem. While searching in google some say that it's a permission settings problem. I tried adding vagrant user to the admin group and by running the following commands:

```
$ sudo groupadd admin
$ usermod -G admin vagrant
```

I also edited `/etc/sudoers` file and added `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to the env_keep option, commented out the `Defaults requiretty` line and added the line `%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`. 
I get the same error.

Here's my bootstrap.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS='' read -r -d '' NODEAPP <<'EOF'
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello Universe.\n');}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Listening at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
EOF

cd /usr/share/nginx/html
if [ ! -f app.js ]; then
    echo "$NODEAPP" >> app.js
fi
forever start -w app.js
```

And here's my Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos65NODE"
  config.vm.box_url = "centos65NODE.box"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.10"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but it might be a pathing issue. My setup was different (Ubuntu, Puppet), but the symptoms of being able to execute Forever from the command line but not through provisioning are similar. I had to provide a full path to the Forever executable for it to run via provision. e.g. - "/usr/local/node/node-default/bin/forever start app.js"

Comment: well i guess i have to use it inside virtualbox without vagrant

Answer (score 0):

Remember, provisioning scripts run as root